# how many stream analytic jobs can you have for one iot hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I have created two stream analytic jobs for one iothub having multiple devices.
But, the data is being received only to the first created stream analytic job. Even if I stop that, no data is being sent to the second stream analytic job.

Is that a bug or am I missing something. Or is it simply that one iothub can have only one stream analytic job.

Comment: Every IoTHub consumer group has a limit on maximum number of concurrent readers. As long as that limit is not hit, you can have multiple jobs. Note that even within a single job, based on how the query is written, there could be multiple consumers. If one job works and other doesn't you will have to check activity logs and debug.

Comment: You can use `eventHubClient.GetConsumerGroup("<your consumer group name>").CreateReceiver("1", DateTime.UtcNow);` to check your two consumer groups can receive messages or not. Here is [a sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted#receive-device-to-cloud-messages) you can reference.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your both stream analytic jobs are using the same Consumer Group such as *$Default* from the same IoT Hub.

So, create for Azure IoT Hub two Consumer Groups dedicated for each ASA job, in other words, each ASA job will have own Consumer Group.

- the following screen snippet shows an example of the plugin ASA job to the IoT Hub, where the Consumer group can be selected specifically for each job.

[image: iothub]